# JavaScript: Checking to see if an array of objects doesn't have a duplicate depending on a particular property?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have an array of objects, a objects can look something like this:

```
{name: "object1", type: "event", props: {internalid: 1}}
{name: "object2", type: "event", props: {internalid: 1}}
```

I want to loop through the array of these objects and I want to create a new array of the objects with no duplicates (For me two items are duplicates if they have the same `internalId` in the `props` property)

I was wondering what would be the best and most efficient way to get "Unique" objects from the original array and in to the new one based on the `internalId` property?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're best way would probably be to create a new, empty array and simply iterate through the original array, adding elements to the new array if they don't already exist there (based on your unique definition). I don't see your solution getting much simpler than that.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this pretty easily with the [uniq](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) method from [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) or [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/).  They will optimize things a bit if your array is already sorted.  Both libraries have well documented code, so you could always look at their approach to the problem.

Here is an example:

```
var objs = [{
    name: "object1",
    type: "event",
    props: {
        internalid: 1
    }
}, {
    name: "object2",
    type: "event",
    props: {
        internalid: 1
    }
}, {
    name: "object3",
    type: "event",
    props: {
        internalid: 2
    }
}];

var result = _.uniq(objs, false, function (item) {
    return item.props.internalid;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this using Dojo's `array` functionality.  The filter uses a temporary object that contains the ids that you have already come across.

```
require(["dojo/_base/array"], function(array){

    var data = []; // load the data

    var _lookup = {};
    var uniqueArray = array.filter(data, function(item) {
        var key = item.props.internalid;
        if(_lookup[key] !== true) {
            _lookup[key] = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
    delete _lookup;

    //use uniqueArray
});
```